# focusable not working in a recyclerview - why?

Tags: android

Hi i have a main recyclerview which is set to vertical and inside that recyclerview i have another recyclerview which is set to horizontal and inside horizontal recyclerview i have cardview with imageview and textview, i'm currently making my layout for android t.v so in order to work this code i have to add focus in my cardview so that user can easily navigate through the cards but the issue is if i'm adding

```
android:focusable="true"
```

in my cardview nothing works, my guess is because i have 2 recyclerviews that's why cardview is not receiving focus any idea how to fix it..

Here's my code

This is my main recyclerview

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerviewMainCarousels"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/>
```

This is my second recyclerview

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewCarousel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>
```

And this is my cardview

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bollyAlbumCardView"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:contentPadding="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp">

                <com.hirazo.utilities.HZImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/playIcon"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_play_new"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation) instruction

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line of code somewhere (Adapter?)

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```